# Differences in Typescript Array Usage

Tags: typescript

I am primarily a backend developer but have been tasked with working on a TypeScript project.

Would someone please clarify the following? Specifically...

1. why doesn't "Snippet 1" compile but "Snippet 3" does? Am I really forced to use an interface if I want the code to work?
2. why does "Snippet 2" usage of `prototype` loose type safety and expect an item of `type: any` instead of `type: string`?

### Snippet 1

```js
let state = {
  ids: Array<String>
}

let id = "123"

state.ids.push(id); // ERROR: property 'push' does not exist on type
```

### Snippet 2

```js
interface State {
  ids: Array<String>
}

let state: State = {
  ids: new Array<String>()
}

let id = 123; // NOTE: type: number vs. type: string

state.ids.prototype.push(id); // NO ERROR: since prototype is of type: any
```

### Snippet 3

```js
interface State {
  ids: Array<String>
}

let state: State = {
  ids: new Array<String>()
}

let id = "123"

state.ids.push(id); // WORKS
```

Comment: In snippet 1 you are not *creating an array*. Nor are you *defining a type*. You just assign the array constructor to `ids` and use a generic for it.

Comment: `ids: Array<String>` this is just a type definition, you are not creating any array in this way. When you call `new Array()` instead you are creating an array, and the only TS part is `<String>`. By the way the use of the array constructor in javascript is discouraged

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina not a type definition. You can't define types inside an object literal

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. I advise you to start from plain JavaScript to have a clearer mind of what is happening

Comment: @VLAZ true, it's interesting to see [how it's compiled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAzmCGYggXggbwFAQgSwCZQC4IBBAJ1NgE8AeAZTFOwDsBzAPnQF8g)

Comment: It's pretty much a reference to the Array global object

Comment: One question per question please. Also, your second snippet does not, nor can it work, since `state.ids` doesn't have a `.prototype` property. This should be throwing both a compilation error *and* a runtime error.